# Parsing XML with namespace

Tags: python, xml, python-2.6, elementtree

With this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope>
    <subject>Reference rates</subject>
    <Sender>
        <name>European Central Bank</name>
    </Sender>
    <Cube>
        <Cube time='2013-12-20'>
            <Cube currency='USD' rate='1.3655'/>
            <Cube currency='JPY' rate='142.66'/>
        </Cube>
    </Cube>
</Envelope>
```

I can get the inner `Cube` tags like this

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree

t = ElementTree()
t.parse('eurofxref-daily.xml')
day = t.find('Cube/Cube')
print 'Day:', day.attrib['time']
for currency in day:
    print currency.items()

Day: 2013-12-20
[('currency', 'USD'), ('rate', '1.3655')]
[('currency', 'JPY'), ('rate', '142.66')]
```

The problem is that the above XML is a cleaned version of the original file which has defined namespaces

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
    <gesmes:subject>Reference rates</gesmes:subject>
    <gesmes:Sender>
        <gesmes:name>European Central Bank</gesmes:name>
    </gesmes:Sender>
    <Cube>
        <Cube time='2013-12-20'>
            <Cube currency='USD' rate='1.3655'/>
            <Cube currency='JPY' rate='142.66'/>
        </Cube>
    </Cube>
</gesmes:Envelope>
```

When I try to get the first `Cube` tag I get a `None`

```
t = ElementTree()
t.parse('eurofxref-daily.xml')
print t.find('Cube')

None
```

The root tag includes the namespace

```
root = t.getroot()
print 'root.tag:', root.tag

root.tag: {http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01}Envelope
```

Its children also

```
for e in root.getchildren():
    print 'e.tag:', e.tag

e.tag: {http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01}subject
e.tag: {http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01}Sender
e.tag: {http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref}Cube
```

I can get the `Cube` tags if I include the namespace in the tag

```
day = t.find('{http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref}Cube/{http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref}Cube')
print 'Day: ', day.attrib['time']

Day:  2013-12-20
```

But that is really ugly. Apart from  cleaning the file before processing or doing string manipulation is there an elegant way to handle it?

Comment: What do you mean by "defined namespaces that do not exist" the URIs do not have to exist on the web

Comment: @Mark I mean that those URIs return a 404 not found. If that is not a problem then the problem is another one.

Comment: That is not a problem for namespaces, and including the namespace is the correct way to do it as per the lxml (which is a superset of ElementTree) [tutorial](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces) - and this way of using namespaces is much nicer than I see in other XML APIs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a more elegant way than including the whole namespace URI in the text of the query. For a python version that does not support the `namespaces` argument on `ElementTree.find`, [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/index.html) provides the missing functionality and is "mostly compatible" with `xml.etree`:

```
from lxml.etree import ElementTree

t = ElementTree()
t.parse('eurofxref-daily.xml')
namespaces = { "exr": "http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref" }
day = t.find('exr:Cube', namespaces)
print day
```

Using the `namespaces` object, you can set it once and for all and then just use prefixes in your queries.

Here is the output:

```
$ python test.py
<Element '{http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref}Cube' at 0x7fe0f95e3290>
```

If you find prefixes inelegant, then you have to work on a file without namespaces. Or there may be other tools out there that will "cheat" and match on local-name() even if namespaces are in effect but I don't use them.

In python 2.7 or python 3.3, or higher, you could use the same code as above but use `xml.etree` instead of `lxml` because they've added support for namespaces to these versions.

Comment: What version of XML you used? Notice that the problem happens with the second unmodified version, the one with namespaces. You got the root `Cube` which has no attributes. Try `find('Cube/Cube')`.

Comment: `find(match, namespaces)` is new in Python 3.3

Comment: Actually the ``namespaces`` argument is also available in python 2.7, which is what I used for testing my answer before posting it. But you've used the 2.6 tag in your question so I've updated my answer to take this into account.

Comment: It is not documented: http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-objects

Comment: `lxml` is not included in 2.6 but your answer is good enough so I'm accepting.

Comment: I did not say it was included with Python 2.6.